# Storage, index support for high dimensional(2048) feature vector

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, cube

I have feature vector of 2048 dimensions, it is normalized.

And I need to store it in postgresql with fast access for search.
Search is conducted using either cosine similarity or euclidean similarity.
So far I have tried:

1. I have tried gin index, distances functions does not use index at all, so sequential scan sucks.
2. [cube](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/cube.html) extension, but has 100 dimensional constraint, one can bump it up to 128, after that either index fails or data is too big to store in a row.
3. Splitting 2048 dimensions into 16 128 pieces and storing as cube datatype in a separate table (linked with id). Bu at the end I have to calculate sum of distances. Although it was better than sequential scan.
4. PCA - for dimensional reduction, accuracy is not enough for 128 dimensional vector.

Would be helpful:

1. Extension for this type of workload ( with at least euclidean distance and index support)
2. Improving on algorithm for splitting search in `3`
3. Other open source database system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that PostgreSQL (as good as it can be) has fundamental limitations.

I have found [elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) to be very good alternative to it.

It has all the support for basic structured data/types and built in support for all L1, L2 and cosine distances for high dimensional vectors.

I have tried with 250.000 samples, search takes less than a second.